# Correct way to write folder names in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, list, matlab, character

I have a list of folders, I want to write a matlab file to read each of them and make a new list of their subfolders.

```
folder_dates = ['20210426']; %there might be much more

for i=1:length(folder_dates(i))
    sessions = dir(folder_dates(i));
    sessions(1) = [];
    sessions(1) = [];
    
    for j=1:length(sessions)
        roi_regions_folders = dir(fullfile(sessions(j).folder, sessions(j).name));
        roi_regions_folders(1) = []; % .
        roi_regions_folders(1) = []; % ..
    end
    
    
end
```

However, when I write "folder_dates(1)" in the Command Window, I receive

> 2
> as the output (I think the first character).

I want the output be

> '20210426'

How should I change that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create multiple folders, you can define them with an array of strings or a cell array of chars.

**variant with string array**:

```
folder_dates = ["20210426", "20210427"]; %there might be much more

for id=1:length(folder_dates)
   mkdir(folder_dates(id));
end
```

**variant with cell array**:

```
folder_dates = {'20210426', '20210427'}; %there might be much more

for id=1:length(folder_dates)
   mkdir(folder_dates{id});
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes for your folder names.

When you `folder_dates = ['20210426'];`, you create an 1 x 8 array containing 8 *char* elements.

When you `folder_dates = ["20210426"];`, you create an 1 x 1 *string* array cotaining 1 *string* element.